# Heap overrun error is resolved by removing a heap allocated variable?

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, heap-memory, valgrind

While investigating a `glibc` crash I get this `valgrind` error:

```
Invalid write of size 8
   at 0x43A3D2: DataAudit::DataAudit(DataAuditModel*, QWidget*) (DataAudit.cpp:15)
   by 0x42D318: MainWindow::createNewDataAudit(DataAuditModel*) (MainWindow.cpp:191)
   by 0x48CA09: MainWindow::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) (moc_MainWindow.cpp:65)
```

`Invalid write of size 8` [seems to indicate](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/quick-start.html) a heap block overrun.

Here are the two problem classes, pared down for conciseness:

```
class IAWidgetModelOwner : public IAWidget
{
public:
    explicit IAWidgetModelOwner(IAWidgetModel *model, QWidget *parent = 0) :
        IAWidget(model, parent),
        pointer1(MAIN_WINDOW),
        pointer2(MAIN_WINDOW) // See note below
        { }

private:
    MainWindow *pointer1;
    MainWindow *pointer2;  // See note below
};

class DataAudit : public IAWidgetModelOwner, public Ui::DataAudit
{
public:
    explicit DataAudit(DataAuditModel *dataAuditModel, QWidget *parent = 0) :
    IAWidgetModelOwner(dataAuditModel, parent),
    _dataAuditModel(dataAuditModel) // DataAudit.cpp:15
    { ... }
    ...

private:
    QList<RawLog*> _rawLogs;
    DataAuditModel *_dataAuditModel;
};
```

The puzzling thing, is that the `valgrind` error **does not appear** if I remove `pointer2` from `IAWidgetModelOwner` by commenting out the indicated lines above. Removing all references to `_dataAuditModel` also resolves the error.

Since I am not actually calling `new` or `malloc` in this class, I don't understand how the automatic heap allocation could cause such an error. I feel like I'm at a dead end in investigating this bug.

What am I doing wrong, or where is a good place to look next?

<sub>Note: MAIN_WINDOW is a globally defined `MainWindow` pointer pulled in from `Globals.h`</sub>

Comment: don't use raw-pointers and you will not have memory-management errors.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow,`MainWindow::createNewDataAudit()` is not allocating an object large enough for your `DataAudit` object. Focus your debugging efforts there.

Since not enough memory is allocated, initializing the pointer member `_dataAuditModel` causes the overrun. When you remove the member `pointer2` from the base class, you are shrinking the size of the `DataAudit` object to fit in the memory allotted to it by `MainWindow::createNewDataAudit()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting this. Although it didn't lead me to my actual solution, it helped me greatly in understanding exactly what the problem was and helped me to debug. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Surprise surprise, the actual error was in code that I chose not to include:

```
class IAWidgetModelOwner : public IAWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
```

I used the `Q_OBJECT` macro, but it had no `signal` or `slot` declarations. Either of the following solved my problem:

1. Remove `Q_OBJECT`
2. Define a slot `public slot: mySlot() {}`

In reality, I thought I *had* declared one of the member functions as a slot.

Comment: Later, I ran into a similar issue again and resolved it by cleaning my Qt project and rebuilding.